Do tribes dissolve when united into one nation?
In my world there is a mostly agricultural kingdom with roughly medieval technology in a temperate, heavily forested land with very harsh terrain and climate comparable to New Zealand. In its place were once various tribes and petty kingdoms, but about five or six centuries ago they were united through conquest after one of them developed a communication method that could bypass the harsh terrain and allow for quick messaging and coordination between armies, towns and cities.
Do the constituent tribes gradually dissolve when ruled from the top as one nation for a long time? It seems so - in early medieval France, for instance, there were the Frankish tribes, but later on when France was one kingdom or before that when there were independent duchies and smaller kingdoms, you don't hear about there being different French 'tribes'. But there were different regional cultures - isn't this basically the same thing, just they're not called tribes anymore?
What exactly is going on here? Would the people in the kingdom most likely still identify as being from specific 'tribes' or not?

Questions about what people will do or why they are doing them are not permitted on this site. You get to decide the motivations for characters in your world not us.

Weird that you thought of medieaval France first: there is a famous saga about 12 tribes s/where in the Levant, who got first united under a renegade Egyptian prophet, then under a line of kings; they ended half-enslaved, half client state of the Persian empire. Nice read, well written, although it asks for much suspension of disbelief at times.

As a german, I do identify as citizen of that federal state. As someone who lived his entire life in Baden-Wuerttemberg (one of the states making up germany), that too is a (lesser) part of my identity. As someone with swabian (a german "tribe" I suppose) dialect and culture, I am also a swabian. It depends on the context - when talking to an actual foreigner, It'll probably be most relevant that I'm german. When talking to other germans, the other two parts might become relevant. Especially when (jokingly! in my case anyway...) playing up enmnities between tribes. Or east and west. Or N-S...

You should speak to some Italians... The amount of town-nationalism is incredible; if you're from Siena or Firenze or Modena you really identify as being that (and think anybody from Reggio is a 'testa quadrata'); or Roma vs Lazio, or ... ; and that's apart from North vs South. Or just like others mentioned, anybody in Bayern is very much from Bayern in Germany. Both are more recent unifications (200y give or take?) than your scenario --- but in our faster, hyper-connected times, so I'd feel it's an indication. Or all the dialects and accents in the UK.

There isn't a single right answer to this question
But there may be guidance to help you with your worldbuilding.
The native First Nation people within the United States have to many degrees preserved their cohesiveness — some with greater success than others. Some of the tribal identities today are very strong, well organized, and exist despite existing within the influence of the United States. Others have gone extinct, either destroyed during the colonial period or having given up their identities over the nearly 300 years since colonization. Therefore, for your consideration, some rough rules...

No nation can exist without either violence or the infrastructure of law (which is just the codified threat of violence). No tribe as a functioning legal authority can exist independent of the larger nation without that nation's permission (or "acquiescence" if you prefer a less inciting word). Should the time come when the tribe can function as a legal authority without the larger nation's permission, the larger nation exists only as a definition and isn't just ripe for conquering, it's probably past due.

If the larger nation is tolerant of sub-culture identity (e.g. it celebrates freedom, had to negotiate for peace, or sees the tourist value, etc.), the tribes are more likely to remain as cultural identities. If the larger nation is not tolerant of sub-culture identities, the tribal identity will either be driven underground or will go extinct.

Any distinction that causes regular friction between tribal members and non-tribal members will cause action that will contribute to forcing the tribe to leave the nation or to become extinct within it. Whether or not the tribal identity continues is therefore a balance between permissiveness and tolerance on one side and the all-too-human distaste for differences on the other. That, and the greater the inconvenience of stamping out the identity the more likely it will continue.

In many cases the tribal identity will be at odds with the national identity (otherwise there isn't a question). If the national identity is more desirable (which can happen over time, but after nearly 300 years there's still strong tribal identities in the U.S.) the tribal identities will fade. If the tribal identity has something unique or is specifically championed then it will not. It's theoretically possible for the tribal identity to be more desirable than the national identity and the national identity dissolving over time... but I'd need to defer to @AlexP's greater knowledge in these matters for an example (if one exists).

Finally, there's a big difference between native tribes and/or groups eventually bonding together to form a national identity, which (IMO) is far more likely to result in the individual cultural identities (which are already similar) dissolving, and the collision of invading people and native tribes/groups, which generally (and perhaps always) are culturally different and would lead to friction that would favor the sub-culture remaining distinct... if it can survive the invasion/colonization action (the example being native tribes in the U.S. given the founding principles of the U.S., albeit nowhere near a perfect example).


Conclusion
As with many things worldbuilding, there simply isn't a "natural law" that conveniently exists that you can apply to your work that gets you off the hook of making a decision. This is one such case. Whether or not you want a sub-culture identity to persevere under the influence of a primary culture is entirely up to you. It remains only to craft the relationship between the two cultures to determine to what extent one survives and the other doesn't.
If you want further help crafting such a situation, please submit a second question with...

Greater detail about the two cultures,
A description of your goal,
An explanation of how you've crafted the two cultures to meet that goal,
And a clear description of where you've become stuck.

... knowing that there isn't a "right answer" and avoiding a basic "is this believable?" question that's rarely necessary and would be better suited for Chat (The Factory Floor) anyway.
Cheers!

Another example would be the English, Irish, Scotts, and Welsh.  They were united under one, top-down, often-iron-fisted rule for hundreds of years, and yet even today confusing one ethnic group for another is a sure way to make them grumpy with you.

Identities are not one or the other, but can exist in counter-intuitive or hierarchical way. The preferred identity one self-describe can change during one's lifetime or environment depending on various cases. For instance, one could feel European and scorn their national identity, or they could feel European as well as their national identity (lets say, French). Or they could refuse to self-identify as European in other than geographic way. Going deeper, one could consider themselves to be Parisean, then French, and finally European.

@Colombo You're not wrong, but I do believe you're thinking futher outside the box than the OP intended. Worldbuilding is about creating reasonable and rational simplifications because, to paraphrase an old scientist, the only way to simulate an infinitely complex system is with that system, itself.

There are two different dynamics at play here. There is the political dynamic where people have governments at different levels. We have national governments, regional governments, and so on down to the neighborhood level.
Then, there are the natural associations that people have. We form groups at 75 to 150 people. We form groups based on actions such as work groups. We form groups based on mutual interests. We form groups based on family ties, languages, and other cultural affinities.
In France, the traditional languages formed distinct regions. People from Alsace used to speak a form of German. Breton is a Celtic language. A native speaker of one of these languages may not be able to understand a different speaker. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_France
When we look at the Roman empire, it ruled a huge area for a long time. Yet, places still kept their traditional languages and ethic identities. Only some individuals transcended their traditional identity and became Roman Citizens. When the empire fell apart, those places rebuilt their own national governments.
What will dissolve tribal boundaries will be both education in a common language and the speed of travel and communication. When those do not occur, the traditional tribal boundaries will survive no matter what the government organization does.

"Only some individuals transcended their traditional identity and became Roman Citizens": All the free men in the Roman Empire were made citizens in 212 CE by the Edict of Caracalla. (And for the two hundred years before that Roman citizenship was given left and right to just about anybody who bothered to apply.) (Oh, and former slaves became citizens when set free. Given that the Romans were very liberal with manumitting their slaves, there were a lot of Roman citizens of foreign descent ever since the 1st century BCE...)

It all depends on what is the meaning of the word tribe.
Words are not magical.
To the extent that the word tribe has a defined meaning in anthropology it tends to refer to a sort of proto-state; a group of people who recognize a common authority but which lack most of the attributes of a real state. Medieval France did not have tribes in the technical sense because there were no such pre-statal groups of people.
In practice, outside the technical meaning in anthropology, when speaking of civilized countries we generally use words such as state, region, or ethnic group. We use the word tribe only when required by law and custom, for example the Indian tribes of the USA, or when speaking of hunter-gatherers without political representation, or, most often, when speaking of the constituent ethnic groups of less than fully civilized countries. Whether the last of these usages is considered derogatory or not is impredictable; exercise due caution.
It should not matter whether you call the Provençals and the Bretons tribes or ethnic groups: they do exist, their people do have a shared identity, and the regions of France do have political dimensions. While it should not matter, in practice it would be grossly impolite to call them tribes, so don't do it.
The original meaning of the Latin word tribus was "one of the electoral constituencies in which the Roman people was divided". There were originally three of them, and that may be why they were called tribes; as the people became more numerous, so did the tribes, up to a total of 35 in the late Republic. For the Romans, the word did not have any "ethnic" connotations, it was just a technical term for the constituencies which made up the Assembly by Tribes.
The Romans used a system similar to the American Electoral College. Each of the constituencies had one vote, e.g. for a candidate consul. And oh yes they gerrymandered their tribes. Just like in the USA, it was perfectly possible for a man to be elected consul in spite of most people voting for somebody else.

No.
See: native tribes in USA, Canada, Australia, Rwanda — or pretty much anywhere the British Empire set up a nation. See breakaway republics of the Soviet Union. See Kurds in Iraq/Iran/Syria. See Jews throughout history everywhere.


Do the constituent tribes gradually dissolve when ruled from the top as one nation for a long time?

No they dissolve almost immediately if it's achieved through conquest. The men are mostly dead or enslaved. The leaders are dead, the keepers of tribal knowledge are dead.
Unless there is a reason for the conquerors not to wipe out the tribal powerbase it's history.
Medieval is a lot different from the main colonisation we know about. The big ones were mainly external. It's a different thing when it's internal. Much more wholistic. You cannot have leave these people with any strength.

Divide et impera. Look at europe, for example. The tribes, together with their rivalry, do exist to some extent, even though not all of them. That might, among other things be because you can unite tribes in many ways without killing the entire (and valuable) work force.

@Burki thats when it's an outside aggressor. When it's an internal one, one tribe conquers and either destroys or assimilates the other. If you enslave them it's best not to do it in situ. Sell them off to outsiders or distribute them around.
